# Is it possible to center align items in a ListView?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

At the moment, the display is like this:

[image: Image showing items currently left-aligned]

I've tried adding

```
.list-cell {
  -fx-text-alignment: center;
}
```

into the CSS but this seems to have no effect. Am I using the wrong thing or is this not possible?

TIA

Comment: The [`textAlignment` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textAlignmentProperty) only has effect when the text is multiline. Use the [`alignment` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) (`-fx-alignment: center ;`).

Comment: Thanks again! If you want to add it as an answer, I can set it as correct

Comment: java doc is your friend :)